# version difference error on worker and driver for pyspark in jupyter notebook - Mac

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, worker

i got the following error message when i try to create a simple dataset and print it out.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName("SparkSessionExample")\
.master("local[4]")\
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "target/spark-warehouse")\
.config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "localhost")\
.getOrCreate()\

# make some test data
columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [
     (1, 2, 0),
     (2, 0, 1)
]

# create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.show()

  File "/Users/USERNAME/server/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 267, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

i tried multiple way to reset the PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON variable, but it doesn't work. hope anyone who solved this problem can help me to fix it!

Comment: Can you provide more information on your environment ? Distribution ? SparkContext ? Cluster ?

Comment: I am running spark on my local jupyter notebook and not connecting to any cluster

Answer (score 0):

PYSPARK_PYTHON is the python env that sits on the executor used by executor to executor your spark code

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.show()
```

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON is the python env that sits on the driver used by driver to run your main python process

```
columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [
     (1, 2, 0),
     (2, 0, 1)
]
```

The version of your PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON didnt match. I would try make sure those two python are exists on the driver/executor and under same version.

If your executor does not have any python, you can just ship the dependency of your PYSPARK_PYTHON to the executor.

Comment: import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'], this gives me 'python3', and os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] gives me an error. could you explain by step how to match the version of those ttwo?

Comment: this means your PYSPARK_PYTHON is set in the system enviroment but PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON is not set. you can do this in the terminal by export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=path/bin/python to explicity set your PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON.

Comment: just keep in mind, PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON does not need to be sitting on your driver box, instead it should sit on the executor box. If your executor box just have python 3.7 instead of 3.6, you can do two things:

1. create a python 3.7 venv on your driver box and use that as PYSPARK_PYTHON
1. or follow this [link](https://jcrist.github.io/venv-pack/spark.html) to zip your venv to the executor, which personally prefer this.

Comment: or sorry, you are using local spark instances, I would just point the PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to the same path/bin/python.